# If space is expanding, how can I see a galaxy 12 billion light years away where it is today?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion

Assuming space is expanding (and that seems plausible), photons from a galaxy that have been traveling for 12 billion years must have been traveling on a curve to get to us due to the fact that where we see the light today is not where the object is now. And yet there is no distortion in the light from that galaxy. Why?

Comment: Why would the fact that "where we see the light is not where the object is now" imply the light is traveling on a curve? Let's ignore the expansion of space and just imagine an object receding from you at 0.8c in flat spacetime. Then if it's 10 light years away from you in the year 2010, a photon it emits at that moment will reach you in the year 2020, so it will *appear* only 10 light-years away from you in 2020, when in reality it will have moved 8 light-years between 2010 and 2020, so it'll really be 18 light-years away in 2020. But the light traveled in a straight line--what's the problem?

Comment: Well, technically the light is shifted and broadened (in frequency) due to Doppler-effects and expanding space.  In that sense, one could argue that the light is distorted.  However, there is no need for curved space to explain this effect.  Though on a related note, we have observed evidence of [gravitational lensing](http://imagine.gsfc.nasa.gov/news/grav_lens.html), which is an example of light being distorted by the curvature of a massive gravitational object (e.g., a galaxy).

Answer (score 1):

You and your buddy are standing on some kind of sheet of stretchy material.  Someone is slowly stretching the material in all directions at once, which causes you and your buddy to slowly get further and further apart.  Your buddy rolls a ball towards you.  When you rolled the ball, you and your buddy were 20 feet apart.  As the ball rolls, the sheet is, as described, expanding.  By the time the ball reaches you, you and your buddy are 25 feet apart.

Analogy key:

- you = telescopes observing distant stars
- buddy = distant star
- ball = photon
- stretchy sheet = space
- person stretching the sheet = dark energy??  TBD.

As you can see in this analogy, no curved paths or distortion are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it does not travel on a curve. Just the space through which it travels has expanded. There is no need for curved trajectory to explain the expansion of space.